# Oracle Database Connectivity in Asp.net Vs 2010 (Attempt to load Oracle client libraries threw BadImageFormatException.)

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle

I am installed Oracle Client 12 c and Add Reference System.Data.OracleClient

string oradb = "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION =(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST = **.**.**.**)(PORT = 1522)))(CONNECT_DATA =(SERVICE_NAME = ****)));User ID=****;Password=****Unicode=True";

Implemented code below

```
        OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(oradb);
        OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT AUXPTYPE,AUXPTYP2 FROM SILAS14_CDS_DIRECTORY WHERE CDSID=RRRRR";
        cmd.Connection = con;
        con.Open();
        OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Error Getting  :Attempt to load Oracle client libraries threw BadImageFormatException.  This problem will occur when running in 64 bit mode with the 32 bit Oracle client components installed.

Comment: nobody ever reads exception messages :( _"This problem will occur when running in 64 bit mode with the 32 bit Oracle client components installed"_ means that you have install 32 bit Oracle client components and tries to run them in 64 bit mode.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1: You may need to install another instance with Oracle Client 12 c - 64 bit, then you can run your codes correctly.

Option 2: Or, you can try to change the project build type in Visual Studio from `Any CPU`/`x64` to `x86` to make your DB call in 32 bit mode.

To change build type: Right click the project in Visual Studio -> Select **Build** tab -> **Platform target** -> **x86**.

Comment: I have done all  these thing but this is not working and i have installed winx64_12201_client Oracle client

Comment: After you installed the 64-bit Oracle Client, please remove the reference `System.Data.OracleClient` and add the reference to 64-bit version. If no lucky, please refer: [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24237891/13378146)